# How to use select_related in save method of a model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Lets say I have the following models:

```
from django.db import models

class X(models.Model):
    ...

class Y(models.Model):
    ...
    x = models.ForeignKey(X, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Z(models.Model):
    ...
    y = models.ForeignKey(Y, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now, in a normal query, I could chain `select_related()` functions like so:

```
z = Z.objects.select_related('y__x').get(pk=1)
```

This would automatically get the related `X` and `Y` objects. Now, what if I wanted to use `select_related()` in the `Z` class's overridden `save()` method. How would I go about doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use it in the `save` method, since `select_related` is a queryset method, not instance method

However if you do this

```
z = Z.objects.select_related('y__x').get(pk=1)
....
z.save()
```

you'll get the expected behaviour, because `y` and `x` will be joined thanks to the `select_related` there won't be additional database queries.

If you do the following without `select_related` -

```
z = Z.objects.get(pk=1)
....
z.save()
```

you still can refer to `y` and `x` in your `save` method. In this case django will do additional database query to fetch related data.